# How to call the iOS search button with javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile-development

I've got an searcharea where I've used

```
<form><input name="search"/></form>
```

which enables and shows the search button on iOS mobile keyboard.

My question is now, how can i find this search button in code so that i could add an onclick="(callFunction)" for example like i would be able to do if I had created an button myself. Any help or input highly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using and `type="search"`, so you can attach an event handler to the `search` event like:

```
$('input[type=search]').on('search', function () {
    // search logic
});
```

or:

```
<input type="search" name="search" onsearch="OnSearch(this)"/>
```

Doc:

> Occurs when the user presses the ENTER key or clicks the 'Erase search
>   text' button (x) in an input:search field.

Ref: http://help.dottoro.com/ljdvxmhr.php

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rb684u8o/